# Saving output from a for loop in a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a for loop that goes through dataframes:

```
dataframes = [df_1, df_oslo_2, df_3, df_4, df_5]
cost_dict = {}

for name in dataframes:
    df = name
    list_cost = df.loc[5:128, ['A','B', 'C']].values.tolist()
    list_cost_tuple = tuple(tuple(sub) for sub in list_cost)
    cost_dict[name] = list_cost_tuple
```

I want to save them in a dictionary but I i get an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'`

Is there anything wrong with the loop i made, or is it not possible to store it in a dictionary?

Comment: Remove the double equals checking for comparison `cost_dict[name] == list_cost_tuple`.

Comment: You are passing a dataframe to `cost_dict[name] == list_cost_tuple`.  name is not the name of the dataframe, it is the dataframe itself.

Comment: @CodeKorn It still doesnt work

Comment: The key of a dictionary (the object inside the brackets) needs to be hashable. DataFrames are not hashable, so consider using a string or an integer as a key.

Comment: It gets 3 columns and rows 5:125 from det different dfs @OneMadGypsy

Comment: @abh ~ It looked like nonsense, but right after I asked I decided to look it up to double check. Apparently, it's legit. I guess it's a convoluted slice?

Comment: Okey, nice to know! Do you have a good way to to it here? I'm not that well versed with dictionaries @tilman151

Comment: You could modify your input list to a dictionary `dataframes = {"df_1": df_1, "df_oslo_2": df_oslo_2, "df_3": df_3, "df_4": df_4, "df_5": df_5}` and iterate over it with `for name, df in dataframes.items()`